# Looking for Open-Source Odoo Frontend Project with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, odoo, crm

I am searching for an open-source project that involves the front-end development of Odoo using ReactJS. I would like to find a GitHub repository where I can clone the code and potentially contribute. My aim is to enhance my skills in both Odoo and ReactJS development through practical experience.

Could anyone please provide me with recommendations for existing open-source projects that meet these criteria? I am specifically interested in projects that focus on Odoo's frontend components and are built using ReactJS. Any pointers to relevant repositories or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, if there are specific keywords or search strategies I should use on GitHub to locate such projects, please feel free to share those as well.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!